# Using powershell only, sort a text file with 300 lines, first by string length and then, once in that length, set them all alphbetically

Tags: powershell

I am trying to do this as a one liner in powershell, so that I can move on to check these strings against a check string.
The trouble I am having is that no matter what I do, I can only set it by string length.

The following attempts failed to get the required result.One does text great, the other by length successfully. I have also tried to pipe them in but I believe that neither accept pipeline input.

Your help is appreciated as  am new to powershell.

```
PS C:\Users\IEUser> Get-Content Desktop/dict.txt | Sort-Object 
PS C:\Users\IEUser> Get-Content Desktop/dict.txt | Sort-Object -Property Length
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given the sample array `$toSort`:

```bash
$toSort = @(
    'abcdefghwxyefg'
    'abcdefghghijkl'
    'abcdefghwxyefgabcdzx'
    'abcdefghwxyefgabcdef'
    'abcdzx'
    'abcdef'
    'abzxc'
    'abcde'
    'wxy'
    'efg'
    'abcdefgh'
    'ijklmnop'
)
```

You can use [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-7.2) to sort the array first by the `Length` property and then by *alphabetical order* like this:

```bash
$toSort | Sort-Object Length, { $_ }
```

Thanks [Mathias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68329174/using-powershell-only-sort-a-text-file-with-300-lines-first-by-string-length-a/68329308?noredirect=1#comment120761928_68329308) for pointing it out, I was previously using `{ $_[0] }` which would sort only the first char of each line.

---

Including how the actual answer should be:

```bash
Get-Content Desktop/dict.txt | Sort-Object -Property Length, { $_ } |
    Out-File path/to/sortedDict.txt
```

---

If you want to have some fun with [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable?view=net-6.0) you can accomplish the same using first [`OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=net-6.0) to sort by `Length` and [`ThenBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.thenby?view=net-6.0) *alphabetical order*:

```bash
[Linq.Enumerable]::ThenBy(
    [Linq.Enumerable]::OrderBy($toSort, [Func[object, int]]{param($s) $s.Length }),
    [Func[object, string]]{param($s) $s }
)
```

Comment: You too should make a YouTube channel. Trying to convince powershell pops (*Mklement*) to make one as well.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Oh, well I feel ashamed now. You're totally right. Please, post it as answer, I'll delete mine.

Comment: Meh, you're close enough already. Update your answer and I'll remove my comment so you don't have to be embarrassed instead ;-)

Comment: @AbrahamZinala would love to see mklement on any learning platform like udemy or pluralsight, 100% would pay for that lol

Comment: I can back that as well lol including @Mathias

Comment: Thank you very much. Having run that in the console, I see it works perfectly. Waht I can't see is how to impliment my document into it. Thanks again in advance

Comment: @Kartibok just do it like you're doing on your question, with `Get-Content` and then pipe it to `Sort-Object Length,{ $_ }` and then you can pipe it to `Out-File` if you want to have a sorted copy. I can edit my answer to show if you want.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Much appreciated. Works perfectly

Comment: @Kartibok Glad it worked, I think we should thank Mathias who pointed out the right answer :P

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thank you for your input, much appreciated.